# How to change the hit box area of a HTML Canvas component?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have been making a basic HTML Canvas game for a website using the tutorial found on w3schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_intro.asp

But I now have an issue where the image for my character doesn't fill up the whole rectangular hit box of the component because the image has blank pixels in some areas around the edges.

This causes collisions to happen between the character and other objects, on the blank parts of the image, so the game ends despite no direct collision between the image and objects because the hit area wraps around the image as a rectangle.

What I would like to know is whether there is a solution where I can have the hit box area wrap tightly to the image, instead of it being rectangular, so that there are no invisible corners causing false collisions?

Or do components have to be rectangular and this is unchangeable?

Thanks.

Comment: You can implement all sorts of hittest logics. The easiest is indeed rectangles or circles. To adress your problem, have you considered defining hitboxes for each obstacle (invisible rectangles)? I'd need to see your code to help further.